# User input, and timer

Tags: java

I'm working on a program to see if you name capital and state pairs of all USA states. What i want, is that I have a timer and the user inputs all the states and capitals as `State - capital` mapping. But when I create it. I saw that the user can just enter the same state and capital 50 times, and he/she would have 50/50 score. I used arrays for the States, and Capitals.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exam {

public void exam() {

    String state[] = {"alabama", "alaska", "arkansas", "california", "colorado", "connecticut", "delaware", "florida", 
        "Georgia","Hawaii", "Idaho",  "illinois", "indiana", "iowa", "kansas", "Kentucky", "louisiana", "maine", "maryland", 
        "massachusetts", "michigan", "minnesota", "mississippi", "missouri", "montana", "nebraska", "nevada", "new Hampshire",
        "new Jersey", "new mexico", "new york","north carolina", "north dakota", "ohio", "oklahoma", "oregon", "pennsylvania", 
        "Rhode island", "South carolina", "south dakota", "tennessee", "Texas", "utah", "vermont", "virginia", "washington",
        "west Virginia", "wisconsin", "wyoming"};
    String capital[] = {"montgomery", "juneau", "phoenix", "little Rock", "sacramento", "denver", "hartford", "dover", "tallahassee",
        "atlanta", "honolulu", "boise", "springfield", "indianapolis", "des moines", "topeka", "frankfort", "baton rouge",
        "augusta", "annapolis", "boston", "lansing", "st. paul", "jackson", "jefferson city", "Helena", "lincoln",
        "carson city", "concord", "trenton", "santa Fe", "albany", "raleigh", "bismarck", "Columbus", "Oklahoma city",
        "salem", "harrisburg", "providence", "columbia", "pierre", "nashville", "austin", "salt lake city", "montpelier",
        "richmond", "olympia", "charleston", "madison", "cheyenne"};

    int y = 0;

    String ad = " - ";

    String input;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Start writing states and capitals [State - capital] (type stop to stop)");

    input = s.next().toLowerCase();

    for(int x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
        input = s.next().toLowerCase();
        if(input == state[0] + ad + capital[0]) {
            System.out.println("Correct");
            y++;
        } else { 
            System.out.println("wrong");
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use a HashMap instead of an array. The key could be the state and the value can be the capital of that state.

```
HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();  
map.put("Texas","Austin");
```

Once the user enters the right state and capital, delete that entry from the HashMap.

```
map.remove("Texas");
```

Refer to https://www.javatpoint.com/java-hashmap if you have never implemented HashMaps before.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i'm going to see if that works, but do I need to create multiple hashmaps, or can I put all in the same map?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, i have never worked with Hashmap's, but i read about them, but i don't understand what I'm suposed to do?

Comment: 1 HashMap would suffice. Multiple are needed if the key is being repeated. In your case since the state name would be the key, it is never going to be repeated.

HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();  
map.put("Texas","Austin");
map.put("California","Sacramento");
...

HashMaps use hashing so they have O(1) access time. When the user enters a state name, say "X" and the corresponding capital name as "Y", check :
if (map.get("X").equals("Y")){
    //increase score
    map.remove("X")
}

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to add the correct x values to a Set (no duplicates), and see, whether its size is 50.